# Fine tuning diffusion inpainting/outpainting

Tags: stable-diffusion, diffusers

I have created a dataset consisting of images of different individuals. For each instance, the dataset contains three different images: the original and complete image, an image showing a masked region, and an image where the mentioned masked region has been removed or cropped out.

My goal is to fine-tune a diffusion model to receive the cropped image and the mask as input, and then complete or reconstruct the image to make it similar to the original, complete image. Could you please guide me on how to approach this task of training a diffusion model for image inpainting or completion?